# Need help for adding userss and groups in Openldap server

Tags: openldap

I am using Centos 5.3 to configure my openldap server. Everything is going ok. The problem which I am facing is how to add users and groups in my ldap server.

1. My slapd.conf is

   ```
   # vi /etc/openldap/slapd.conf



   database    bdb 

   suffix            "dc=test,dc=local" 

   rootdn            "cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=local" 

   rootpw            123
   ```
2. Now I start my LDAP service

   ```
   [root@srv1 openldap]# service ldap start 

   Checking configuration files for slapd:  bdb_db_open: Warning - No DB_CONFIG file found in directory /var/lib/ldap: (2) 

   Expect poor performance for suffix dc=test,dc=local. 

   config file testing succeeded 

                                                              [  OK  ] 

   Starting slapd:                                            [  OK  ]
   ```
3. Now I perform search

   ```
   [root@srv1 openldap]# ldapsearch -x -b "dc=test,dc=local" "(objectclass=*)" 



   # extended LDIF 

   # 

   # LDAPv3 

   # base <dc=test,dc=local> with scope subtree 

   # filter: (objectclass=*) 

   # requesting: ALL 

   # 



   # search result 

   search: 2 

   result: 32 No such object 



   # numResponses: 1
   ```
4. I create a ldif file inside /etc/openldap folder

   ```
   [root@srv1 openldap]# vim base.ldif 



   # base.ldif 


   # Build the root node 

   dn: dc=test,dc=local 

   dc: test 

   objectClass: top 

   objectClass: domain
   ```
5. Now I create add two OUs

   ```
   [root@srv1 openldap]# vim Add_2_OUs.ldif 



   # To add two OUs i.e Sales and Marketing 

   dn: ou=Sales,dc=test,dc=local 

   ou: Sales 

   objectClass:organizationalUnit 



   dn: ou=Marketing,dc=test,dc=local 

   ou: Marketing 

   objectClass: organizationalUnit
   ```
6. Now add the OUs

   ```
   [root@srv1 openldap]# ldapadd -D "cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=local" -W -x -f Add_2_OUs.ldif
   Enter LDAP Password: 
   adding new entry "ou=Sales,dc=test,dc=local"

   adding new entry "ou=Marketing,dc=test,dc=local"

   [root@srv1 openldap]#
   ```
7. Now I perform search

   ```
   [root@srv1 openldap]# ldapsearch -x -b "dc=test,dc=local" "(objectclass=*)" 



   # extended LDIF 

   # 

   # LDAPv3 

   # base <dc=test,dc=local> with scope subtree 

   # filter: (objectclass=*) 

   # requesting: ALL 

   # 



   # test.local 

   dn: dc=test,dc=local 

   dc: test 

   objectClass: top 

   objectClass: domain 



   # Sales, test.local 

   dn: ou=Sales,dc=test,dc=local 

   ou: Sales 

   objectClass: organizationalUnit 



   # Marketing, test.local 

   dn: ou=Marketing,dc=test,dc=local 

   ou: Marketing 

   objectClass: organizationalUnit 



   # search result 

   search: 2 

   result: 0 Success 



   # numResponses: 4 

   # numEntries: 3 

   [root@srv1 openldap]#
   ```

If you think that there is some technical or logical mistake please guide me so I may improve it more.

Also please guide me that How can I add groups and users in my ldap server ? 
I am also adding DIT (Directory Information Tree) diagram for your easiness.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To manage the objects in your dyrectory, you can use different tools, my preferred one is LAM (Ldap Account Manager).
You can get it for free at
https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/
It integrates the classic tree view from phpMyLdapAdmin, and the more powerfull predefined views, for users, groups, computers and domains.
Whit this tool you can easily add users and groups to your directory in a comfortable web environment.